# How to retrieve data from dictionary by dynamic variable in AWS Step Function?

Tags: aws-step-functions

My step function has two input variables: dictionary and simple string.

```json
{
"workflows": {"A": "A_UIID", "B": "B_UUID", "C": "C_UUID" },
"name": "A"
}
```

Is it possible to retrieve data from input dictionary **workflows** by another input variable **name** not using Lambda?

I tried to do so in Pass state like

```json
    "GetId": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "id.$": "$['workflows'][$.name]"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.domain_workflow",
      "Next": "Next"
    }
```

or

```json
    "GetId": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "id.$": "$['workflows'][$['name']]"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.domain_workflow",
      "Next": "Next"
    }
```

But it fails in the execution stage.

It does work if pass the actual value instead of variable:

```json
 "GetId": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "id.$": "$['workflows']['A']"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.domain_workflow",
      "Next": "Next"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to pick a value from an object using a dynamic key.  Neither [JSONPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75747193/is-there-an-way-to-get-dynamically-the-path-of-object-in-jsonpath) nor intrinsic functions seems to offer a solution.

However, it's possible to refactor the problem to pick a value from an *array* using a dynamic *index*.

Given a Pass state that picks a workflow at an index with the `States.ArrayGetItem` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-arrays):

```json
{
  "Type": "Pass",
  "Parameters": {
    "uuid.$": "States.ArrayGetItem($.workflows, $.index)"
  },
  "OutputPath": "$.uuid",
  "End": true
}
```

When the input is:

```json
{
  "workflows": [ "A_UIID", "B_UUID", "C_UUID"],
  "index": 2
}
```

Then you get the output:

```json
"C_UUID"
```

Comment: Thanks @fedonev. That was also my disappointing finding that it's not possible to lookup config values by dynamic keys. Thanks for the confirmation. I awarded you the bounty I promised for the response 