# Is there an way to get dynamically the path of object in jsonpath?

Tags: jsonpath, aws-step-functions

## What i am trying

I have a configuration object like so:

```json
// set to $.config
{
  "DE": {
    "hello": "hallo"
  },
  "EN": {
    "hello": "hallo"
  },
  "ES": {
    "hello": "hola"
  }
}
```

which has been set in the variable `$.config` in a step function and a var `$.language` set to `DE`.

Now i would love to select the right key in doing something like:

```yaml
Next Step:
  Type: Pass
  Parameters:
    localizedHello.$: $.config[$.language].hello
                              ^ this sadly does not work
  ...
```

Do you know a better way then using a `pass step`?

## What i tried

I know the example below works but it is really a cumbersome approach!

```yaml
Its is German:
  Type: Pass
  Parameters:
    localizedConfig.$: $.config.DE
  ResultPath: $.selected
  Next: Next Step
Next Step:
  Type: Pass
  Parameters:
    localizedHello.$: $.selected.localizedConfig.hello
  ...
```

Also there is no [Intrinsic Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) for it, like:

```yaml
Next Step:
  Type: Pass
  Parameters:
    localizedHello.$: States.Get(States.Get($.config, $.language), 'hello')
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not a way to do what you're asking.

Fortunately, we're building a spec for JSON Path now.  I've added your use case to a [proposal](https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base/issues/156#issuecomment-1470693328) that would support what you're looking for.